# how to update a Db2 table row and delete an existing row?

Tags: db2

DB2 Table ZB_BILL_ERR :

```
PROCESS_DATE    CURR_PROCESS_DT  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  SEQ_NUM    ERROR_REASON 
07/14/2013  07/14/2013  A123456789    1     Trancode Invalid
07/15/2013  07/15/2013  B987654321    1     Adjustment code invalid
07/16/2013  07/16/2013  A123456789    2     Multi Single ind invalid
```

Expected Output :

```
PROCESS_DATE    CURR_PROCESS_DT  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  SEQ_NUM    ERROR_REASON 
07/15/2013  07/15/2013   B987654321   1     Adjustment code invalid
07/14/2013  07/16/2013  A123456789    2     Multi Single ind invalid
```

The process date of the latest row of A123456789 will have the oldest process date of the account in the table, in this case which is 07/14/2013 And delete the oldest row of A123456789

Comment: ... I'd start by making the table unique on `A123456789`, if possible (you only want one row per id), then either update-or-insert in a procedure, or use a `MERGE` statement (if your version of DB2 supports it).  What version of DB2, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To identify the most recent record, use

```
  row_number() over (partition by account_number
                     order by curr_processs_dt descending
                    ) as aging
```

which will rank your rows in descending date order within an account. Pick rows where aging = 1 to get the most recent.

To get the earliest date for an account:

```
select account_number, min(process_dt) as first_processed
  from input
  group by account_number
```

So let's put this together into one (somewhat complex) SQL statement

```
MERGE into ZB_BILL_ERR m
USING ( 
        with g as
        (
          select account_number
               , min(process_dt) as first_processed
            from ZB_BILL_ERR 
            group by account_number 
        )
        select i.*
             , row_number() over (partition by account_number
                                    order by curr_processs_dt descending
                                   ) as aging
             , first_processed
            from g
            join ZB_BILL_ERR i  on i.account_number = g.account_number
      ) as x
  ON m.account_number = x.accout_number
  WHEN MATCHED and x.aging = 1  THEN
    UPDATE process_dt = x.first_processed
  WHEN MATCHED and x.aging > 1  THEN
    DELETE
;
```